# Import excel spreadsheet into mysql database not working in mac

Tags: php, mysql, html

Hi my code works fine on PC but it is not working in Mac If I have 5 rows of data all rows are correctly inserting in PC but the only one-row field is inserting in mac os.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $c = 0;
    while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
        $ID = $filesop[0];                                                                          $team = $filesop[1];
        $publisher = $filesop[2];
        $magazine = $filesop[3];


        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO logsheet 
                                (ID,team,publisher,magazine) 
                        VALUES ('".$ID."','".$team."',
                                '".$publisher."','".$magazine."')");
        $c = $c + 1;
    }

    if($sql){
        echo "You database has imported successfully. You have inserted ".$c ." recoreds";
    }else{
        echo "Sorry! There is some problem.";
    }
}
```

Where am in going wrong.

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** _mysql_*-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are **wide open to** [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: The Mac uses different line endings than the PC. Which one did you export the file on?

Comment: Do you think that is the problem caused for Mac not to work correctly

Comment: According to the documentation, yes. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Thanks, man That works perfectly.